# Different Progress Elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to use 3 different colored Progress Bars in HTML5. How can i change the color in a css class?

I know about this command:

```
progress::-webkit-progress-value {background-color: #aaa !important;}
```

But it is not working in css classes.

Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: How exactly did you attempt to use it with classes?

Comment: Something like:
<progress class="progress3" max="100" value="{{a}}"></progress>

Comment: And the corresponding CSS…?

Comment: @jakobmoehlenkamp Have a look at this demo https://jsfiddle.net/vyspiansky/x089pmvL/ Hope it helps you somehow. I see a proper colour styling at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the selectors. Apparently when Chrome encounters a ruleset that has an invalid selector from its point of view, it ignores the whole rule.

In Mozilla, `::-moz-progress-bar` allows to specify the color of the progress bar, whereas the same property for webkit `::-webkit-progress-bar` allows to style the whole track. For the bar itself in Chrome/Blink/Webkit, use `::-webkit-progress-value`, which only works when setting  `progress { -webkit-appearance: none; }`.

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.red::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<progress class="red"    value="70" max="100"></progress>
<progress class="blue"   value="30" max="100"></progress>
<progress class="yellow" value="50" max="100"></progress>
```

> **Note**: For `::-webkit-progress-value` to take effect, `appearance` needs to be set to `none` on the `<progress>` element.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-bar